# Atualização de dados hierárquicos utilizando hierarchyId

Tags: sql, dados-hierárquicos

Olá.
Tenho a seguinte tabela na SQL Server 2008

[image]

O objetivo é atualizar o campo Valor em um filho e acumular no pai. Por exemplo:
Se no registro de id 12 eu colocar o valor 31 no campo valor, seu pai direto (8) deve receber o valor 31.
Se no registro de id 11 eu colocar 25, seus pais diretos (6,4,3,1) devem receber mais 25 no campo valor.

Existe alguma forma de fazer isso sem utilizar loopings (e CTEs recursivas)?

Answer (score -1):

Eu penso que você quer algo desse gênero, estou certo?

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
UPDATE     Atividades mae
LEFT JOIN  Atividades filho on
           (mae.id_mae = filho.id)
SET        mae.valor = mae.valor + 31,
           filho.valor = 31
WHERE      filho.id = 12;
```

Comment: Considere que o nome da tabela é "Atividades"

Comment: O script não roda.

Comment: Eu fiz isso para mysql, talvez seja isso, porque eu rodei no workbench normal.